# sqlite database connection refused on laravel-voayger

Tags: laravel, sqlite, laravel-5, voyager

Using Mac OS X and Laravel 5.8 with package [voyager](https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager)

getting error while login
[image]

database config:
`config/database.php`

```
'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE/..', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
            'foreign_key_constraints' => true,//env('DB_FOREIGN_KEYS', true),
        ],
```

env config
`.env`

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
DB_DATABASE=database\database.sqlite
```

Comment: please try to remove the DB_DATABASE env line, I think the database config should be an absolute path

Comment: with the same config I ran another project, that's running without any error. Are you sure about it?

Comment: database_path() returns an absolute path, your DB_DATABASE env value is relative. Also in your config you have this line `env('DB_DATABASE/..',`  that it seems an error to me, it shoud be `env('DB_DATABASE',`. I would comment out the url config too.

Comment: @dparoli if I set absolute path it seems not found
in my case:
`"Database (Users/mac/Desktop/Dev/test/laravel-voyager/database/database.sqlite) does not exist. (SQL: PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;)"`

Comment: do exist a `database/database.sqlite` file? it should exists, sqlite dirver needs a database file, in case you can create a new one with `touch database/database.sqlite`

Comment: yes, it exists.

Answer (score 0):

I ran these and solved the issue.

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```